# Detect Dead code in Java on runtime

Tags: java, code-coverage, metrics

In development we use EclEmma to verify having a good test coverage. Since we start now a big refactoring task involving a lot of sourcefiles will have to be replaced, I wonder if it would be possible to run something similar on our servers to verify we haven't forgotten to remove some classes or methods.

Since the frameworks we use do a lot DI and Reflections, static code analysis won't help.

Is there something analysing on rumtime if all my classes and mothods have been called while server runtime?

Regards,
Michael

EDIT: This analysis won't run in production but in integration/acceptance test phase.
It's not planned as a finite answer to delete all recognized classes/methods, but as hint/reminder what to delete.

EDIT 2: An explanation why this question is to be closed would be nice

Comment: how can you be sure that code was just not called during your trial ? I assume the false-positive rate would be high. If you have a good test coverage for the project, then this is trivial. If not than I guess you cannot be sure about the usage of code parts and removing those is too dangerous

Comment: Could you not use a memory profiler configured to the methods/classes you've removed? If they're instanced you should see usages of them, if you've successfully removed all references to them they should never get initialized.

Comment: Do you have to run this analysis in production, or do you have a dev environment where you could mimic prod use? If so, you could try using java.lang.Instrumentation to record the use of classes. http://blog.javabenchmark.org/2013/05/java-instrumentation-tutorial.html . There may even be tools that do this automatically for you.

Comment: By the way, I suggested running it in a dev environments, because the instrumentation will impact performance

Answer (score -1):

Try Cobertura tool, it helps to analyse better but not sure whether it will satisfy your need or not.